# Is there a keyboard shortcut to open/switch to an app that is seeking attention from the Dock?

Tags: macos, keyboard, dock

Can I program a key to intercept any app that seeks attention?

I think that Linux, Gnome or KDE, used to have this a long time ago, ctrl-A or something like that is the hot key to activate the space / app that needs attention on other OS.

What automation or tool might do this on macOS?

Comment: I normally just use command-tab until I get to the offending app (or have to use the mouse). This becomes tedious when you have a bunch of apps open. It would be nice to have an immediate shortcut.